Passpartout Authentication not possible. No salt value stored
I have a simple nodejs authentication done with passpartout:
require('dotenv').config({path: './.env'});

const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const passport = require('passport');
const UserDetails = require('./db/userDetails');
const session = require('express-session');

const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const ordersRouter = require("./routes/orders.js")
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth.js");

 
 
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', handlebars.engine({ extname: '.hbs' }));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(flash());

// Passport settings

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(UserDetails.createStrategy());
passport.serializeUser(UserDetails.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(UserDetails.deserializeUser());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/scripts', express.static('node_modules'))
 
// Main Routing

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', authRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter)
 
 
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.sendStatus(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

async function init(){
  const doc = await UserDetails.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      username:process.env.DEFAULT_USER
    }, 
    {username:process.env.DEFAULT_USER, password:process.env.DEFAULT_PASS}, {
    new: true,
    upsert: true // Make this update into an upsert
  });
  console.log(doc);
};
init();

module.exports = app;

The file UserDetails.js:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');
 

// Connecting Mongoose
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);

// Setting up the schema
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String, 
  dailyDistance: Object,
  monthlyDistance: Number,
  lastLogged: Date,
  salt: String
});


// Setting up the passport plugin
User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose,{saltlen:32});

module.exports =  mongoose.model('User', User);

The file auth is a simple post route handler:
router.post('/login/password', async (req, res, next) =>{
   
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        badRequestMessage: 'The username does not match any account',
        failureMessage: true,
        failureFlash: true
    })(req, res, next)
});

Suddennly, I cannot login anymore. A message appear:
"Authentication not possible. No salt value stored"
I use dockerized mongo server.
